# Not able to generate querydsl Q classes with Azure CosmosDB because @Entity annotation is not present

Tags: spring-data-jpa, azure-cosmosdb, querydsl

I am just trying to do a POC using spring boot data jpa along with Azure CosmosDB and query dsl. My plugin in pom.xml looks like this where I am using `com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor` Annotation processor which is supposed to scan files with `@Entity` Annotaion But in my case Entity class is annotated with `@Container` instead of `@Entity` And because of that querdsl is unable to generate `Q` files. I am wondering is there a way to do it with `@Container` annotated class?
Pluggin in `pom.xml` 

4.0.0

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
2.5.6
 

com.configuration
Pagination-and-filtering
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
Pagination-and-filtering
Demo project for Spring Boot

<java.version>11</java.version>



org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-data-jpa


org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-web

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.querydsl/querydsl-jpa -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.querydsl/querydsl-apt -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    </exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
                        <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

My entity class

```
public class UserEntity {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private Integer age;
    private String profession;
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    public String getProfession() {
        return profession;
    }
    public void setProfession(String profession) {
        this.profession = profession;
    }
    
    
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well according to the documentation, you might be able to achieve this using 2 options:

Option 1: `querydsl.unknownAsEmbeddable`

> set where unknown non-annotated classes should be treated as
> embeddable (default: false)

https://querydsl.com/static/querydsl/3.1.2.BUILD/reference/html/ch03s03.html

Example of Usage:

```
         <plugin>
            <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
                        <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                        <options>
                            <querydsl.entityAccessors>true</querydsl.entityAccessors>
                            <querydsl.listAccessors>false</querydsl.listAccessors>
                            <querydsl.useGetters>true</querydsl.useGetters>
                            <querydsl.unknownAsEmbeddable>true</querydsl.unknownAsEmbeddable>
                        </options>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
                    <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
                    <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

---

Option 2:  Using `@QueryEntities(ClassWithContainerAnnotation.class)`

https://querydsl.com/static/querydsl/4.4.0/apidocs/com/querydsl/core/annotations/QueryEntities.html

Example package-info.java

```
@com.querydsl.core.annotations.QueryEntities({com.onescorpin.jpa.AbstractAuditedEntity.class, com.onescorpin.jpa.AbstractAuditedEntityAsMillis.class})
package com.onescorpin.metadata;
```

Ref: https://github.com/wcandy0088/nova/blob/master/nova-new1/core/operational-metadata/operational-metadata-jpa/src/main/java/com/onescorpin/metadata/package-info.java

Comment: Hi, thanks It did solved my problem. However, I run into another issue where it says `CosmosRepositoryFactory does not support Querydsl!` Have you tried to test querdsl with cosmosdb before?

Comment: No sorry @GiteshkumarJha my suggestion would be to create a new ticket, with the complete stacktrace to see if anyone can help.

Comment: Created one here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70075347/cosmosrepositoryfactory-does-not-support-querydsl